# I am not able to save image in external storage in android

Tags: java, android

My logcat is as follow pls help me

```
4-21 01:29:26.288 21536-21536/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-21 01:29:26.324 21536-21536/? D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
04-21 01:29:26.331 21536-21536/? W/ReflectionUtils: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.MessageQueue#enableMonitor()#bestmatch
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:338)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:375)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.callMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:800)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.tryCallMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:818)
        at android.os.BaseLooper.enableMonitor(BaseLooper.java:47)
        at android.os.Looper.prepareMainLooper(Looper.java:111)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
04-21 01:29:26.363 21536-21536/? W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
04-21 01:29:26.373 21536-21536/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.quotescreator-2/lib/arm64
04-21 01:29:26.410 21536-21536/? W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
04-21 01:29:26.422 21536-21536/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-21 01:29:26.454 21536-21536/? D/AccessibilityManager: current package=com.example.quotescreator, accessibility manager mIsFinalEnabled=false, mOptimizeEnabled=false, mIsUiAutomationEnabled=false, mIsInterestedPackage=false
04-21 01:29:26.480 21536-21536/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
04-21 01:29:26.481 21536-21536/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
04-21 01:29:26.604 21536-21579/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-21 01:29:26.714 21536-21579/? I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 10c9f68, I74772a33ad
    Build Date                       : 02/07/17
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.07.00.01
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.5.1_RB1.06.00.01.192.038
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
04-21 01:29:26.761 21536-21579/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-21 01:29:28.493 21536-21536/com.example.quotescreator I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:18521828
04-21 01:29:29.956 21536-21536/com.example.quotescreator D/path: /data/user/0/com.example.quotescreator/app_imageDir/UniqueFileName.jpg
04-21 01:29:41.239 21536-21536/com.example.quotescreator I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:18534574
04-21 01:29:41.829 21536-21579/com.example.quotescreator D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x559e61e8e0 (InsetDrawable) with handle 0x559e5cda60
04-21 01:30:55.099 21536-21536/com.example.quotescreator W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
04-21 01:30:55.125 21536-21536/com.example.quotescreator W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

// This is my code

```
    public void SaveImage(View view) {
            // coneverting relative layout in image  to save as we have to save image with text written
            // on it i.e we have to save the whole layout
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(relativeLayout.getWidth(), relativeLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            relativeLayout.draw(canvas);
            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
            File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            File file = new File(directory, "UniqueFileName" + ".jpg");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                Log.d("path", file.toString());
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have already checked if the user has granted permission to external storage or not?

Then try this one (your code does not work for 20 API levels and above):

```
private void saveImageToExternalStorage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
myDir.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
File file = new File(myDir, fname);
if (file.exists())
    file.delete();
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


// Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
// immediately available to the user.
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
            }
});

}
```

thx from [Yar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/525319/yar)